# Set width of image wrapper in gallery with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Example: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xtLmb061/)

Hello I am having a hard time understanding why these three images below will not fit perfectly inline. I am obviously doing something wrong and tried to research this, but haven't had any luck.

Please look at my jsfiddle. Here you can see I am trying to centre the inner_wrapper div containing three images. I was hoping to have the inner_wrapper div the exact width of the SUM of these three images and whatever margins and padding comes with them. My idea for this is to slot these three images perfectly inside the inner_wrapper so there is no unused space white space on either side of the images.

Please only use pure JavaScript.

Thanks

```
<style>
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img {
height: 100px;
width: auto;
}

#outer-wrapper {
background: coral;
}

#inner-wrapper {
left:0;
right:0;
margin: auto;
background: black;
}

</style>

<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.sbckiteboard.com/uploads/Image/features/LU3P4129.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/10853167_1491239897767502_793839217_a.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://adrenalinfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/scoopamatic-kiteboarding-336x210.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var imageWrapper = document.getElementById("inner-wrapper");

var images = imageWrapper.querySelectorAll("img");

var imageTotalWidth = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    imageTotalWidth += images[i].width;
}
imageWrapper.style.width = imageTotalWidth + "px";

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's still whitespace between your images, which is taking up some width.

Either remove all whitespace characters between `<img>` elements ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmq647yk/)):

```
<img src="url"/><img src="url"/><img src="url"/>
```

or:

```
<img src="url"/><!--
--><img src="url"/><!--
--><img src="url"/>
```

Another option would be to add:

```
line-height: 0px;
```

To the parent div ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/1zfx9e06/)).

Personally, this last example has my preference, since it removes the unwanted space without messing with the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you are requesting JavaScript to achieve this. Apologies if this is not what are you trying to achieve, but if you do, I think with only css you will get it http://jsfiddle.net/awLfwttz/3/

Adding/modifying these extra lines:

```
#outer-wrapper {
    background: coral;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this by floating images to left

```
div#inner-wrapper img {
  float: left;
}
```

long story short your problem is not about javascript as you mentioned. you can achieve what you want with different css tricks